# HTML5 Datalist with Readonly Input, is it valid?

Tags: html, html-datalist

I have in my application a html5 datalist like so:

```
<input type="text" list="mydatalist" />
<datalist id="mydatalist">
   <option>Option 1</option>
   <option>Option 2</option>
   <option>Option 3</option>
</datalist>
```

It works very well until I change the `input` element to `readonly` like so:

```
<input type="text" list="mydatalist" readonly />
```

Then focusing on the input element now does NOTHING...

I have arrived at the assumption that by the specs, a text input with `list` attribute should not also be readonly. Almost like saying, "If you desire readonly, then use a `select` tag". To complicate this matter some more, I feel almost certain that this setup (with `readonly`) once worked on this application. Unfortunately, the answers did not come obvious during my initial web search.

Is my assumption correct, or have I missed something?

Comment: Yeah... So let's talk about this! Could you expand a little bit? I guess it boils down to `datalist` vs `select`?

Comment: It boils down to if you don’t want to allow the user to _make/change_ a selection (readonly), then what sense is a list of _possible values_ supposed to make?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Could you please take a look at the comments under @Naeem's answer to see my point. In summary: the user can TYPE into the box, but only to SEARCH and SELECT from the options provided . The user CANNOT ENTER ANY OTHER STRING.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Datalist vs Select:**

I guess this is what you want, but there is no comparison. `Datalist` is different, `Select` is different.

- datalist is used for autopopulating results from the list, based on user input, while select doesnt do any magic, it just shows all options it has.
- so this makes clear that there shouldnt be any preselected value in datalist(as it is used to auto populate, on user interaction). thus it cant be readonly
- select on other hand is different, it can have a default value, thus it can be readonly.

And yes what you said: "**If you desire readonly, then use a select tag**", yes, according to me its true, coz you cant set anything as selected in datalist, but you can in select.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess what I really was after is this a control that, on user-interaction, populates based on the user's input (==autocomplete), but still ends up discarding any input that has no textual match among the provided options.

Comment: Think about how Select2 or Chosen extends the functionality of native `<select>` elements. That set me thinking that the `datalist` might be an opportunity for that behaviour in html5, without the need for an external package!

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo.. what do you mean by **discardingany input that has no textual match among the provided options**

Comment: I mean: The user types (to pull up matching options), but if they type (or paste) any string not present among the `<datalist>` `<option>`s, then it is not allowed to stay. That's the "readonly" behaviour I am referring to.

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo.. no thats not datalist behavior, you would require to write javascript for that..

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. So we'll all have to keep waiting (?forever) for a rich native autocomplete functionality to come into the html mix. Meanwhile, I'd better accept your answer, 'cause you're basically right. Thanks.

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo.. I dont think anything with such functionality will exist sooner into html.. But lets see if in future some magic happens :)